How do I use gpu from tensorflow within venv?
I'm on Arch, and I've got tensorflow set up and working in the main environment. The gpu is detected and used.
Now I'm trying to do so in the venv, and I'm running into the issue that after the installation in the venv, tensorflow does not detect the gpu
Here is a round idea of what I have tried (after sourcing the venv):
SITE_PACKAGES=$(python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])")
mkdir -p $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib

ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcudart.so $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcublas.so $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcublasLt.so $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcufft.so $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcurand.so $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcusolver.so $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcusparse.so $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcudnn.so $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/  # For cuDNN


ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcudart.so.* $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcublas.so.* $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcublasLt.so.* $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcufft.so.* $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcurand.so.* $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcusolver.so.* $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcusparse.so.* $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/
ln -s $CUDA_PATH/lib64/libcudnn.so.* $SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib/

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$SITE_PACKAGES/cuda/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH


With no luck,  python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))" returns empty list
How do I correctly enable the gpu inside the venv?

You have the wrong approach, you should import tensorflow and it will print to terminal what libraries it is expecting and are missing, use that information to install the correct libraries.
